# Can't access control state in tabcontrol pages ! C#

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, windows-forms-designer, tabcontrol

I have an issue in my project where I have to use "n" number of Usercontrols with tabcontrol's in them.
I am creating txt files with the name and state of all the controls present in the Usercontrols.
The problem is that I can't seem to access the state of the tabcontrol and all the controls in it.

I use this command that works for all the other controls appart from the tabcontrol one...

Any help would be well appreciated.

```
sw = new StreamWriter(filename.txt);

foreach (Control crl in theformname.Controls)
{
       TabPage tab = new TabPage();
       if (crl.GetType() == tab.GetType())
                {
                    sw.WriteLine ("tabcontrol accessed");
                    if (Ctrl.GetType() == cbx.GetType())
                        {
                            CheckBox CheckBoxCrt;
                            CheckBoxCrt = (CheckBox)Ctrl;
                            sw.WriteLine(CheckBoxCrt.Checked.ToString());    //State of the checkbox
                        }
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following would need one layer above TabControl for your UserControl which would be done by mimicking `TabControlList` or `CheckBoxList`

Example

```
public static List<UserControlType> MyUserControlList(this Control control)
    => control.Descendants<UserControlType>().ToList();
```

Here are the current methods for use in the next code block.

```
public static class GenericExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Descendants<T>(this Control control) where T : class
    {
        foreach (Control child in control.Controls)
        {
            if (child is T thisControl)
            {
                yield return (T)thisControl;
            }

            if (child.HasChildren)
            {
                foreach (T descendant in Descendants<T>(child))
                {
                    yield return descendant;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static List<TabControl> TabControlList(this Control control)
        => control.Descendants<TabControl>().ToList();

    public static List<CheckBox> CheckBoxList(this Control control)
        => control.Descendants<CheckBox>().ToList();

}
```

Usage (remember you need to add a list above the TabControl check) using a StringBuilder which can be used to write wherever you want e.g. `filename.txt`.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
var tabs = this.TabControlList();

foreach (TabControl tab in tabs)
{
    builder.AppendLine(tab.Name);
    foreach (CheckBox box in tab.CheckBoxList())
    {
        builder.AppendLine($"\t{box.Parent.Name,-20}{box.Name, -20}{box.Checked}");
    }
}

Debug.WriteLine(builder);
```